# Device for testing real capacity and speed of MicroSD cards

Tags: microsd, test-equipment

There is a problem - microSD cards [are often faked](https://www.eetimes.com/counterfeit-sd-card-problem-is-widespread/), the real capacity is many times less than on the label. I am engaged in video surveillance, for me fakes is critical problem. Before installing a new memory card in the camera, I always have to test the card at least for the real volume (now I'm using [H2testw](https://www.heise.de/download/product/h2testw-50539) utility for it).

So I am looking for a device that can test at least 3 microSD cards at a time without losing r/w speed, and it is desirable to perform such testing by device itself, without a computer or smartphone.

I would be grateful for links to such gadgets and reviews about them, I couldn’t google it myself

Comment: I personally prefer to do this through software since you can test 26 at the same time if you got the USB ports and SD card readers, but if you want a device just for this you probably need to DIY it.